# asp.net - templates

Tags: asp.net, templates

What does the word 'Template' mean when talking about ASP.NET?

For example I have heard about Page template, item template, etc.

What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates (in the case of databound controls such as GridViews) enclose controls that are to be shown for each entry (row, item, etc) the databound control generates.

So, a template containing a Label control bound to a field called RowName will generate a Label, with the Text property set to the value of the RowName, for each row.

Page templating is a similar idea; namely that each page can inherit controls from a "[Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)" page without having to code those controls for each page seperately.